# Returning length of an integer with 000.. in the beginning

Tags: javascript

My problem is simple, yet tricky! I just want to return the length of a number(int), but if I send 0001 in the method, it returns 1. I get that it is eliminating the starting 0s, but I want the exact number, I want it to return 4. 
Is there any other way to do this? Thanks

```
function get_length(number) 
{   
  return number.toString().length
}
```

Comment: Not unless `number` is a string.

Comment: what for do you need this? numbers do not have leading zeros. (as long as it is not `0.something`)

Comment: numbers do not have leading zeros so is it a string to start? If not, than there is no way to do it.

Comment: I have to traverse through the number, so I'm converting the number to string first.

Comment: If you need to traverse it including leading zero's, then it should never be of type `number` in the first place.

Comment: If you set an integer to `0001`, it is simply `1`. The `0`s are completely ignored. You're just doing `1.toString()`, which results in `"1"`.

Comment: So the only way to do this is by passing string as a parameter? eg. ("0001")

Comment: That is correct. As @Niek points out - if you need leading 0's, then it isn't a `number`.

Comment: @ZaidWaseem I update answer - may be `padStart` is what you need

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski the problem with padstart is that not always there will be 000s in the start. User can enter any number like 1254 01255 0002 etc

Comment: @ZaidWaseem I update answer again - in case when you want tho have always 000 in the start

Comment: You'll need to preprocess your number before calling your function. As you already said, your parameter needs to be a string for what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, if you use number as input parameter then it not contains padding zeros - but if you put string as input parameter then it will works

```js
function get_length(number) 
{   
    return number.toString().length
}

console.log("str: ", get_length("0001"));

// you can generate string "0001" from number 1 by using padStart
console.log("gen: ", get_length( (""+1).padStart(4,0) ));
// or like this (always 3 zeros at the number beginning)
console.log("gen2:", get_length( "000"+1 ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Is not possible .Because while passing `0001`.it send as 1 not `0001`.so pass string instead of number

**problem**

```js
console.log(Number(1).toString().length)
console.log(Number(0001).toString().length)
```

**SO**

```js
function get_length(number) 
{   
  return number.toString().length
}

console.log(get_length('0001'))
```